# How to display the model's "name" field using the ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following model

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('Type 1', 'Type 1','Type 2','Type 2')), null=False)
```

I would like to let the user pick instances of MyObject, so i have created a form:

```
class ClassifierSelectMultiForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        myObjects = MyObject.objects.all()
        self.fields["pick_model"] = ModelChoiceFieldCustom(myObjects)
```

When picking the instances, I want the user to be able to see the "name" field so I have overwritten the `label_from_instance` method.

```
class ModelChoiceFieldCustom(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

Output (unexpected):
[image: Actual output]

I've tried changing the `label_from_instance` to return `obj.type` instead `obj.name`.

Output (expected):

[image]

How can i display the name attribute in the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override the `__str__` method of your model instead (the form or the field definition are not the good place to to that):

```py
class MyObject(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=(('Type 1', 'Type 1','Type 2','Type 2')), null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

That way, by calling an instance of your `MyObject` model, it will show by default the `name` attribute of your model.